# ¿Como buscar un objeto en Array?

Tags: typescript, angular4, angular-directivas, objeto

Lo que quiero lograr es, buscar un objeto en `array`. Siempre devuelve `-1` lo que quere decir que no encuentra ninguna coincidencia en `array` para obtener su indice y luego eliminar ese elemento.

Imprimo dos veces el array, la primera para asegurarme que el objeto a buscar esta en el array y la segunda para asegurarme que lo ha eliminado, pero sigue estando el  objeto alli.

Lo he intentado con strings puros, y funciona, pero cuando busco un objeto completo no... ¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
deleteProductFromPurchase(name:string) {
   console.log(this.array);
   const index: number = this.array.indexOf({idCustomer: 998, idProduct: 664, name: "Montaña", price: 200});
   this.testArray.splice(index, 1);
   console.log(this.array);
   console.log(index);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta final:

```
var index:number = this.array.indexOf(this.array.find(x => x.idP == id));

this.array.splice(index, 1);
```

Pimero busco el objeto completo en `array`. Luego ese objeto encontrado lo paso como parametro al merodo `indexOf` para que busque el indice del objeto completo; y eso, finalmente elimina el objeto deseado de `array`.

Comment: Pero en la pregunta digo que lo quiero eliminar. Y luego, tu respuesta es parte de la solución. ¿Que tiene de extraño?

Answer (score 4):

Puedes ocupar el `find`

```
this.array.find(x => x.idCustomer == 998);
```

o `filter`

```
this.array.filter(x => x.id == this.personId)[0];
```

En este caso el indice `[0]` es por si hay una coincidencia o encuentra muchos solo traiga el primero, si quieres buscar muchos mas en el arreglo, puedes quitar el `[0]`

Comment: ¡Funcionó perfectamente! 

Comment: Busca bien, pero ¿como lo elimino? Sigo usando: this.testArray.splice(index, 1); ?

Comment: @JGuerra exacto!

Comment: He utilizado el metodo que me sugeriste y el que estaba usando al priincipio. Finalmente funcionó exactamente como quería. @sioesi